# Adding a button in a FlatList in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a FlatList and I am trying to but a button below the items and when you click on the button it should display the name of the item in an alert.

```
class TopMovies extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        apiTopLoaded: false,
        topPopularMovies: [],
    }
    this.conditionalTopPopular = this.conditionalTopPopular.bind(this);
    this.mybuttonclick = this.mybuttonclick.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
fetch('someurls')
    .then((response)=>{
        response.json()
            .then((popularMovies) => {
                this.setState({
                    apiTopLoaded: true,
                    topPopularMovies: popularMovies.results,
                })
            })
    })    


mybuttonclick() {
    Alert.alert(item.original_title)
}

conditionalTopPopular() {
    if(this.state.apiTopLoaded===true) {
        return(
                <FlatList
                    horizontal={true}
                    data={this.state.topPopularMovies}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <View>

                        <Text>{item.original_title}</Text>
                        <Button onPress={this.mybuttonclick} title="hello"/>
                    </View>
                    )}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                />
            </View>
        )

    }
}
```

I can see all the movie names in the list and I see buttons below the movie names, but when I click on it, it says "cant find variable item". The function `mybuttonclick` should alert the `item.original_title` prop because it displays correctly in the flatlist. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your function like this:

```
mybuttonclick(movieTitle) {
    Alert.alert(movieTitle)
}
```

And pass in the the movie title like this:

```
<Button onPress={this.mybuttonclick(item.original_title)} title="hello"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. it is showing the alerts. But the alerts run as soon as the program runs.

Comment: @craftdeer change `onPress` to `onPress={() => this.mybuttonclick(item.original_title)}`

Comment: Awesome. Could you explain the arrow function in your last comment?

Comment: @craftdeer this [article](https://moduscreate.com/blog/how-to-use-es6-arrow-functions-with-react-native/) explains it very thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the fat arrow function in the `onPress` like this.

```
<Button onPress={() => this.mybuttonclick(item.original_title)} title="hello"/>
```